# How to retrieve a list of installed target framework versions from within visual studio extension?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-sdk, target-framework

I want to retrieve a list of installed target framework versions (including profiles) from within visual studio extension.

Does anybody know how to do this.

Actually this is a list which is displayed in New Project dialog window in framework version combobox.

Answer (score 1):

This is called "Framework Multi Targeting". There is a SVsFrameworkMultiTargeting service that provides the [IVsFrameworkMultiTargeting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsframeworkmultitargeting_methods.aspx) and [IVsFrameworkMultiTargeting2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsframeworkmultitargeting2.aspx) interfaces. And there is the [GetSupportedFrameworks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsframeworkmultitargeting.getsupportedframeworks.aspx) method.

From a package, you can use the following code and then iterate the array of returned strings, where each string contains the Framework + Version + profile:

```
IVsFrameworkMultiTargeting frameworkMultiTargeting;
Array prgSupportedFrameworks;

frameworkMultiTargeting = base.GetService(typeof(SVsFrameworkMultiTargeting)) as IVsFrameworkMultiTargeting;

frameworkMultiTargeting.GetSupportedFrameworks(out prgSupportedFrameworks);
```

Comment: Is a way to retrieve the target frameworks from a console app as well and how can this be done?

Comment: From a console you can get an EnvDTE.DTE instance, which implements Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider, so you can get services: https://www.mztools.com/Articles/2007/MZ2007015.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching for net core and net5.0 and later:

```
dotnet --list-sdks
```

you will get a list like this:
[image]